# startup screen centos 5

Tags: linux, centos, centos5

where can I modify bootup screen in cetos. I runs different messages while booting up and I need to modiy it.
thanks

Comment: "you mean you run different systems" and you want to change the boot option so you can switch between the system you have ?

Comment: no I have centos and when I boot up I want to hide all the boot up messages.
thanks

Comment: I think its under etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit  But I am still try to find out where the splash screen the image at the begining is?

thanks

Comment: The very first splash screen?  You mean the Grub one where you select your kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally hiding the boot messages requires recompiling the kernel, so that you can start the OS in kernel quiet mode. Lately, there are some tools which enable you to do it without recompiling the kernel

you can check splashy 
http://splashy.alioth.debian.org/wiki/installation

or google "fbsplash"